# What causes the segmentation fault? I'm using gcc to compile

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I tried to compile this with gcc and got segmentation fault. I can't figure it out what causes it and how to solve this.

```
struct musiclist
{
   int snum;
   char sname[30];
};
struct musiclist a[100];

struct comments
{
   char com[100][180];
};
struct comments coms[100];

int ncom = 0;
int get_comments(struct comments coms[], int i, struct musiclist a[], int ncom)
{
    char buf[30];
    strcpy(buf, a[i].sname);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.txt");

    FILE *c = fopen(buf, "ab+");
    if (!c)
       printf("Error!");

    char *str = (char*)malloc(180 * sizeof(char));
    size_t len = 0;
    while (getdelim(&str, &len, '$', c)) {
       ncom++;
       strcpy(coms[i].com[ncom], str);
    }
    free(str);

    return ncom;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger like gdb? `gcc -g yoursource.c && gdb a.out`

Comment: How are you calling `get_comments` method?

Comment: Add your `main` function to show us how to reproduce. Also, why do you put braces in strange places?

Comment: snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.txt"); This line looks suspicious

Comment: what is snprintf? Also show us whole code so we know the function call and also getdelim function.

Also Learn to debug

Comment: @Hamza: `snprintf` and `getdelim` are standard functions (C99 and POSIX respectively).

Comment: @Paulo Bu: I call it in main to test it before I try to call it somewhere else: ncom=get_comments(coms,1,a,ncom); where a is of type musiclist and i is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are creating file name:

```
char buf[30];
strcpy(buf, a[i].sname);
```

instead of:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.txt");
```

you should:

```
strcat(buf, ".txt");
```

Comment: used strcat(buf,".txt"); instead but it does exactly the same thing

Comment: If you dont want to debug, then insert logging, ie. printf every where, and see where your printf-s ends. Another place that looks suspicious is getdelim, it returns -1 in case of stream end, so you should rather write: `while (getdelim(&str, &len, '$', c) > 0)`

Comment: Thanks! That was causing the problem, but now the program doesn't do anything so I will have to replace the line with something similar. Well the program was meant to get a song name as songname.txt, and read comments from it until $ delimiter, and I take those comments and put them in a comment matrix, so I have comments for every song and I'm able to have more than one comment for a song.

Comment: Figure it out, why it's not printing anything on the screen. It created a empty .txt file instead of taking the existent one. Thx again! now should work properly

Answer (score 0):

Some where in the program you might have forgotten to make sure that you have fed the number or string into the address of the required variable and instead fed it into the variable itself.like

```
scanf("%d",variable_name);
```

instead of:

```
scanf("%d",&variable_name);
```

And i am new to 'C' so that is as far as i figured about that segmentation fault.